# ClickHouse MergeTree slow SELECT with ORDER BY

Tags: clickhouse

I'm starting to learn CH and seem to be running into dead ends while trying to improve my query speed, the table is created like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.stats(
  aa String, 
  ab String, 
  user_id UInt16, 
  ac UInt32,  
  ad UInt8, 
  ae UInt8, 
  created_time DateTime, 
  created_date Date, 
  af UInt8, 
  ag UInt32, 
  ah UInt32, 
  ai String, 
  aj String) 
ENGINE = MergeTree 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_time) 
ORDER BY(created_time, user_id)
```

and I'm running a query like so

```sql
SELECT ad, created_time, ab, aa, user_id, ac, ag, af 
FROM stats 
WHERE user_id = 1 AND lowerUTF8(ab) = 'xxxxxxxxx' AND ad != 12 
ORDER BY created_time DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

this is the result **50 rows in set. Elapsed: 2.881 sec. Processed 74.62 million rows**

and if I run the same query without the order part, **50 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.020 sec. Processed 49.15 thousand rows**

Why does it seem to process all the rows in the table if in theory the query only has to order around 10k(all the rows returned without the limit) rows? What am I missing and/or how could I improve the speed of CH?

Answer (score 0):

try ORDER BY created_time DESC, user_id

optimize_read_in_order feature were implemented in ClickHouse release 19.14.3.3, 2019-09-10

Comment: About the same results, without order **50 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.021 sec. Processed 16.38 thousand rows** and with order **50 rows in set. Elapsed: 1.855 sec. Processed 24.31 million rows**, I have also updated my CH version to **19.17.5 revision 54428**

Comment: How about statistics for a query without where `WHERE 1`

Comment: Were you after this? **74818400 rows in set. Elapsed: 14.823 sec. Processed 74.82 million rows, 4.31 GB (5.05 million rows/s., 290.91 MB/s.)**

Answer (score 0):

```
CH 19.17.4.11
CREATE TABLE stats
(
    `aa` String,
    `ab` String,
    `user_id` UInt16,
    `ac` UInt32,
    `ad` UInt8,
    `ae` UInt8,
    `created_time` DateTime,
    `created_date` Date,
    `af` UInt8,
    `ag` UInt32,
    `ah` UInt32,
    `ai` String,
    `aj` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(created_time)
ORDER BY (created_time, user_id)

insert into stats(created_time, user_id) select toDateTime(intDiv(number,100)), number%103 from numbers(100000000)


SELECT ad, created_time, ab, aa, user_id, ac, ag, af
FROM stats
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

5 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.013 sec. Processed 835.84 thousand rows,


set  optimize_read_in_order = 0

SELECT ad, created_time, ab, aa, user_id, ac, ag, af
FROM stats
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0

5 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.263 sec. Processed 100.00 million rows
```

Check a difference
set  optimize_read_in_order = 0 VS set  optimize_read_in_order = 1

I don't understand why optimize_read_in_order is not working in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, the "order by" is extremely slow, best practice is if you want to select large volume of data, do not let ClickHouse to select with "order by".

The following SQL will never return after billions of rows scanned ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM market.cn_stock_tick
WHERE time > parseDateTimeBestEffort('2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+08')
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1

Query id: 7c926755-ca00-460b-a3ac-e7d20afa7c56

↗ Progress: 3.91 billion rows, 1.15 TB (9.47 million rows/s., 2.78 GB/s.) ██████████████████████████████▉                                                      (5.6 CPU, 1.63 GB RAM, 1.12 GB max/host) 24%^
Cancelling query.
```